# ::after isn't working with React props but works with regular text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, react-component

I have a react component that gets some properties. One of them is `altText`. I want my `div` to have an `::after`, with `content` being the prop `altText`.

I tried something like (styled-components):

```
const StyledImage = styled.div`
    &::after {
        content: ${props => props.altText};
        color: black;
    }
`;

//

export const Image = ({src, altText, size, scale}) => {
    const imageProps = {
        src: src,
        altText: altText,
        size: size,
        scale: scale,
    }

    return (
        <StyledImage {...imageProps}>
            <img src={imageProps.src} alt={imageProps.altText}/>
        </StyledImage>
    )
}
```

(I'm not talking about the `alt` of the `img`, it's something else)

I call this component as follows:

```
<Image src="https://p.bigstockphoto.com/GeFvQkBbSLaMdpKXF1Zv_bigstock-Aerial-View-Of-Blue-Lakes-And--227291596.jpg" altText="hello"/>
```

That doesn't work. However when I change `content: ${props => props.altText};` to `content: 'hello'` it works perfectly fine. I made sure that `altText` is a `string` an it is.

What's the problem here?

Comment: Have you tried `content: ${props.altText}`?

Comment: That doesn't work, i get the following error: `'props' is not defined  no-undef`

Comment: That's not the problem here

Comment: Can't test at the moment, but have you tried putting quotes around the altText value, i.e. something like `content: '${props => props.altText}';`

Comment: @Roy no worries. If you wanna put that in answer and mark it as correct, will help to show that question is closed

Comment: I can mark it as accepted in 2 days..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(Jayce444's answer)**:

Can't test at the moment, but have you tried putting quotes around the `altText` value, i.e. something like content: `'${props => props.altText}'`;